# How to add Text box validation in webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I have two text boxes. One is for username and other one is for password. Currently I have code for displaying a error message saying "Invalid credentials" if any of the fields are left blank. This takes me to the new page displays the error message and takes me back to the home page where I can enter my username and password again.

I want the validation part to be done near the text box itself. For example if Username textbox is left blank and submit button is clicked, it should display a message like Please enter the username near the textbox itself.

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
      <p class="user_text">USER LOGIN</p>
      <p class="user_name_text">username<span style="color:#f60219;"> *</span></p>
      <p style="padding:8px 0 0 5px;">

        <input type="text" name="username" minlength="2" maxlength="20" class="contact_filed" value="enter your name" onfocus="javascript:clearField(this,'enter your name')" onblur="javacript:fillField(this,'enter your name')" /></label>
     </p>
      <p class="user_name_text1">password<span style="color:#f60219;"> *</span></p>
      <p style="padding:8px 0 0 5px;">
        <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20" class="contact_filed" value="password" onfocus="javascript:clearField(this,'password')" onblur="javacript:fillField(this,'password')" />
      </p>
      <p style="padding:16px 0 0 16px;"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="log" /></p>
      <p style="padding:12px 0 0 16px;"><a href="#" class="read_more1">Create new account</a><a href="#" class="read_more1">Request new password</a></p>
</form>
```

PHP code for validation:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) { 
include('connect.php'); 
$u = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$p = md5($_POST['password']); 
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM $login_db_table WHERE username='$u' AND password='$p' LIMIT 1"); 

if (mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    if ($_POST['remember']) { 
        setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time() + 5000000); 
        setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), time() + 5000000); 
    } else { 
        setcookie('username', $_POST['username']); 
        setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password'])); 
    } 


if($u != "" && $p !=""){
echo '<p>Login successful.</p>'; 
header("Location: main.php");
}

} 

else
echo "Login failed. Please enter valid credentials.";
echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/CashTree/reg/Home/index.html';\",1500);</script>";
    //echo '<p>Login failed. Please enter your correct credentials</p>'; 

}
```

Comment: make a check before submit

Comment: What you want, is probably JavaScript validation. Just check the 2 textboxes before you submit it and prevent the default behavior of the submit button until the inputs are valid. But dont rely on JS vor validation, always validate userinputs on your server too.

Comment: use javascript for validation

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript or jquery for this.
I will illustrate with javascript for your easy understanding.

On your form, change the first line to

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return check_error();">
```

and add a javascript section

```
<script>
function check_error(){
   if(document.getElementById('username_id').value == ""){
      alert("Enter The Username");
      return false;
   }
}
</script>
```

You will need to add the "ID" for each textbox you would like to be verified.

Try this---

```
<script language="javascript">
function check_error(){
    if(document.getElementById('username').value == ""){
        alert('Please Enter Username');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<form method="post" onSubmit="check_error();">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It is a very simple demonstration. but you can certainly build on it.

Comment: Your code is working for me. But when I include action="login.php", it is not validating the textboxes. It is directly redirecting to login.php page.

Comment: Try <form method="post" onSubmit="return check_error();" action="login.php">

Answer (score 1):

You can add an html element near the  element say

```
    <p style="padding:8px 0 0 5px;">

        <input id="uname" type="text" name="username" minlength="2" maxlength="20" class="contact_filed" value="enter your name" onfocus="javascript:clearField(this,'enter your name')" onblur="javacript:fillField(this,'enter your name')" />
<div id="user_name_invalid"></div>
     </p>
```

Then

using jQuery

```
<script type='text-javascript'>
 $("#form").submit(function(e){
   var uname = $("#username").val();
   if(uname == ""){
     $("#user_name_invalid").html("Username is invalid");
     return false;
   }
}
</script>
```

the `return false;` to stop the submitting.

Comment: did you add an id to the form ? you also need to have jquery included in your page.

Comment: Ya I added both Jquery and Id in my form. I think the problem is with login.php redirection. Without validation it is redirecting to login.php page. I tried running it separately, it worked for me but when I include action="login.php" validation part is not working. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7mJG6/6/ check this one its an updated one with action, and could you please post your code ?

Comment: I did a mistake by adding value field. When I removed value attribute from <input> tag it worked for me. The invalid username and password message displays under the text box but when I give valid username and password it is not moving to login.php page. I have added the following line for calling login.php **<form id="myform" method="post" action="login.php" >**

Comment: ok try removing the stopPropagation and preventDefault lines and tell me what happens

Answer (score 1):

For checking if the username is empty just do this:

```
if($_POST['username']=''){
   echo 'Please enter the username';
}
```

If you want this near your textbox, just put it in place where the text will be showing as close to the textbox, so at the beginning of submitting the button. If you want that when this error is showing he shouldn't actually login. You could use a boolean like so:

```
$check=true;
if ($_POST['submit']) { 
   if($_POST['username']=''){
   echo 'Please enter the username';
   $check=false;
   }
   if($check){
   //everything you want to do if it's succesfull
   }
}
```

This will make sure when the `$check=false` it wont go to the next page but stay on the current page, displaying the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HTML 5 new feature of **reququired** attribute on input tags. LIKE an example of :

```
<input type='text' name='txt_username' required='true' />
<input type='password' name='txt_password' required='true'/>
```

To use that above feature, you should need to declare  before   elements.

You can also set custom error meesage using "oninvalid" event and setCustomValidity("") function. A example :

```
<input type='text' name='txt_photo_title' value='' required='true' placeholder="photo name" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter Photo Name !');" />
```

And some sample login form is shown as below. Due to HTML 5 new features, sdata don't reach to sever actually, it excutes in user's browser and so after click submit button, it show error msg instantly. And its design can be maintained by CSS with new css selectors too. Thanks and try it as below sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTMl>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Test Validation Form</h1>
    <hr>

    <form name='frm_test' method='post' action='login.php' > 
        <label> Username :</label>
        <input type='text' name='txt_username' required='true' oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter username !');"/>
        <br/>
        <label> Password :</label>
        <input type='password' name='' required='true' oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter passwords !');"/>

        <input type='submit' name='btn_submit' value='Login'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: browser support might be an issue here, depending on target audience this could not be a solution.